# Jmockit mock addMessage method from FacesContext

Tags: java, jsf, junit, mocking, jmockit

I'm writing component tests for my bean and I'm constantly getting NullPointerExceptions because of the `addMessage()` method from `FacesContext`.

I'm sure it's because of the `addMessage()` method, because if I delete the line the test passes. How do I mock the `addMessage()` method?

**TrendBean**

```
@Named(value = "trendBean")
@ViewScoped
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TrendBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -310401000218411384L;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TrendBean.class);

private ChartPoint point;

private List<ChartPoint> points;

@Inject
private ITrendManager manager;


public String addChartPoint() {
     if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        return null;
     }
     assertNotNull(point);
     final User user = getSession().getUser();
     manager.addPointToUser(user, point);
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null,
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                getTranslation("pointAdded"), ""));
     init();
     return null;
     }
 }
```

**TrendBeanTest**

```
public class TrendBeanTest {

@Tested
TrendBean trendBean;
@Injectable
LoginBean loginBean;
@Injectable
Session session;
@Injectable
ITrendManager manager;
@Injectable
IUserManager userManager;
@Injectable
User user;

@Test
public void testAddChartPoint(@Mocked FacesContext fakeContext) {

    new NonStrictExpectations() {

        {
            session.isLoggedIn();
            result = true;
            session.getUser();
            result = user;
            manager.addPointToUser((User) any, (ChartPoint) any);
            FacesContext.getInstance();
            result = fakeContext;
        };
    };

    Deencapsulation.setField(trendBean, "point", new ChartPoint());

    assertEquals(null, trendBean.addChartPoint());

    }
}
```

**AbstractBean**

```
public abstract class AbstractBean {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractBean.class);

@Inject
private Session session;


public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return session.isLoggedIn();
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return session;
}

public String getTranslation(final String messageKey,
        final Object... formatParameters) {
    return getTranslation(getLanguage(), assertNotNull(messageKey),
            assertWithoutNull(formatParameters));
}

 public static String getTranslation(final Locale locale, final String messageKey,
        final Object... formatParameters) {
    try {
        final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
                "internationalization.messages", assertNotNull(locale));
        return getTranslation(bundle, assertNotNull(messageKey),
                assertNotNull(formatParameters));
    } catch (final MissingResourceException e) {
        assertNotNull(logger)
                .error(String.format(
                        "Severe internationalization error: Internationalization bundle for locale '%s' not found!",
                        locale.toString()), e);
    }
    return String.format("No message found for key '%s'!", messageKey);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in getTranslation("pointAdded")?

Comment: Hey Alfergon, I just added the code for this method. Do I have to mock `ResourceBundle` too?

Comment: In this case I think you could @Mocked AbstractBean and mock the getTranslation() method.

Comment: Thanks Alfergon! :)

Comment: Did it work? Perfect. I think JMockit's the best mocking lib, so I'm always glad to help people out. I'll post and answer so people finding the question can also benefit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, as inside the call to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage` you also call `AbstractBean .getTranslation(String)` you will also need to mock that method.

Something like this:

**TrendBeanTest**

```
public class TrendBeanTest {

@Tested
TrendBean trendBean;
@Injectable
LoginBean loginBean;
@Injectable
Session session;
@Injectable
ITrendManager manager;
@Injectable
IUserManager userManager;
@Injectable
User user;

@Test
public void testAddChartPoint(@Mocked FacesContext fakeContext, @Mocked AbstractBean abstractBean) {

    new NonStrictExpectations() {

        {
            session.isLoggedIn();
            result = true;
            session.getUser();
            result = user;
            manager.addPointToUser((User) any, (ChartPoint) any);
            FacesContext.getInstance();
            result = fakeContext;
            abstractBean.getMessage(anyString); result = "foo";
        };
    };

    Deencapsulation.setField(trendBean, "point", new ChartPoint());

    assertEquals(null, trendBean.addChartPoint());

    new Verifications(){{
        fakeContext.addMessage(withNull(), (FacesMessage)any); 
    }};
}
}
```

Note: I'm doing this from the top of my head with no IDE, so maybe I've overtyped something.